# Backbone - TypeError: search is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have been working on a Backbone.js problem. Full disclaimer - I am fresh to both javascript and Backbone so pardon my poor terminology. My file `city_search.js` is the backbone view for a modal. Recently, I added some change to my home page where it loads `city_search.js` and I keep getting the following error on page load.

`TypeError: search is undefined` pointing at the line `return search.extend`.

Why is search undefined? Does it not reference my `common/views/search` file?

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "require",
    "common/views/search",
    "common/views/view"], function ($, require, search, view) {
    return search.extend({
        placeHolder: "Find city",
        render: function () {
            search.prototype.render.call(this);
            this.$el.find("input").attr('name', 'city');
        },
        selectItem: function (item) {
            this.$el.find("input").val(item.get("name"));
            $("input[name='city_id']").val(item.get("id"));
            this.closeList();
        }
    });
});
```

`search.js`

```
/**
 * Definition of a search module
 **/
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "common/views/view",
    "text!common/views/search.jst",
    "text!common/views/search_list.jst",
    "haway/views/add_place",
    "haway/views/window_matcher", //this was recently added
], function($, _, view, template, listTemplate, add, win) {
    return view.extend({

      //A lot of irrelevant code removed

      /**
      * Selects add new place
      **/

      addNewPlace: function(e) {
        console.log("addNewPlace triggered");
        this.closeList();
        this.win = new win();
        this.win.render();
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Does require.js load the right Javascript files? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: @matt Yes, require.js is loading the correct files

Comment: What does `common/views/search` look like?

Comment: Does search.js have any errors in it? Is it returning the proper value?

Comment: console.log(search) first

Comment: @muistooshort I added search.js. I'm not sure how helpful it would be. There are a lot of parts to this problem because of different use cases. Though I could post them, I think it would be too much to sift through.

Comment: In Javascript, you generally don't want trailing commas at the end of arrays like you have with `"haway/views/window_matcher",`...  I don't *think* it's the problem, but might be worth removing in case require.js is getting confused by it somehow.

Comment: I think this can happen if the module (search) has a syntax error, which causes require to pass undefined to the `define` callback.  Can you try removing most of the code from the search module, so it is very simple? Something like `return view.extend({})`, see if it works with that.

Comment: I haven't used backbone in a while.. but could you point out where you are actually defining `search`. You are loading a module from `common/views/search`, which is calling `view.extend`, but as far as I can see, you haven't defined search anywhere, so the error would make sense?